# Counting the Alignment Frequency on Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Would like to seek help on this Excel matter.

Is there anyway I could get the counts on how many "left alignment" from the table on excel, or it will output a value "1" if it's in left alignment.

For example:

[image]

Comment: you need VBA for this

Comment: could you show me? @simoco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this UDF:

```
Function align(rng As Range) As String
    Select Case rng.HorizontalAlignment
        Case xlLeft
            align = "Left"
        Case xlRight
            align = "Right"
        Case xlCenter
            align = "Center"
        Case xlGeneral
            align = "General"
        Case Else
            align = "Unknown"
    End Select
End Function
```

and then call it like this: `=align(A1)`

[image]

If you want to get `1` or `0`, you can slightly modify formula: `=IF(align(A1)="Left",1,0)`.

Also note, that cells with default aligment (`xlGeneral`) looks like left aligment, but they're not left aligment (cell `A5` in image above). Depends on your needs, you may want to modify formula to `=IF(OR(align(A1)="Left",align(A1)="General"),1,0)`

Comment: Default aligment is `xlGeneral`, I use it in line with left: `Case xlLeft, xlGeneral`:)

Comment: all i am saying is that `xlLeft` <> `xlGeneral`

Comment: @mehow, do you mean that for `xlGeneral` udf should return "Unknown"? it was my first thought, of course `xlLeft` <> `xlGeneral`, but `xlGeneral` looks like left aligment (e.g. in my screen `A5` has general aligment). But maybe you're right)

Comment: well, `xlLeft` = `-4131` but `xlGeneral` = `1`, so if A1 is aligned left and indented 1 point it will show left but A2 is general should show general or default instead of unknown even though it looks like left alignment I think..

Comment: yeah, agree:) I've already modifyed UDF, it returns `align = "General"` for `xlGeneral`:)